# Split a long delimited line into multiple rows

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a very big delimited file without any newline characters. The file is of 22 GB in size, I want to split this file into multiple rows by inserting a newline character after every nth field. I get Memory error in python and in spark I get "Too Many Bytes before newline".

Is there a way I can do this.

Comment: You want to do it by python or pyspark .? I don't know, but try splitting the line in Unix itself, maybe can use fold command. Not sure though, if 22G can be handled with performance, just a suggestion.

Comment: Are your fields always the same length? I mean, are all 10 characters long, or all 20 characters long or something like that? In that case you can try either `sed -e 's/.\{20\}/&\n/g file_name` or `split -b 20 file_name` from the unix command line. See https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/69059-split-based-number-characters.html

Comment: Can we see the code that’s giving you the memory error?

Comment: I was able to achieve this by reading the file in chunks. But it takes around an hour or so. I have access to a large hadoop cluster and wanted to do this using spark. Sorry for replying late.